# Многопоточность,Таненбаума

Tags: информатика

В книге Таненбаума "Операционные системы" приводится такое описание многопоточности:

> "Например, если одному из процессов нужно прочитать слово из памяти (что занимает несколько тактов), многопоточный процессор может переключиться на другой поток. Многопоточность не предлагает настоящей параллельной обработки данных. Одновременно работает только один процесс, но время переключения между процессами сведено до наносекунд."

Какой смысл переключаться со считывание слова на другой процесс, если это не параллельная работа? Почему процессору не закончить считывание?

Comment: Ну Вы же там читали и про планировщик, который выделяет каждому потоку некоторый промежуток времени, и по его истечению переключает на другой. Очень умный планировщик мог бы понять, что поток не фигнёй занят, а слово читает,  но всех случаев не предусмотришь, и чем умнее - тем больше ресурсов нужно на сам планировщик.

Comment: @MBo Нет,еще не было планировщика.Мне непонятно ,что будет с потоком(который читает слово из памяти),когда из него переключатся на другой.Он все равно продолжит считывание?

Comment: Похоже Танненбаум написал это определение в те времена, когда реальная многопоточность в CPU (или нескольких CPU с кэш-когерентностью в SMP) была еще не доступна потенциальным читателям его книг

Comment: Что касается вашего вопроса -- `"Он все равно продолжит считывание?"` -- ответ, **да**. Машинная инструкция считывания будет либо полностью завершена, либо полностью отброшена (тогда исполнения потока после его последующего возобновления начнется с нее)

Answer (score 1):

> Мне непонятно ,что будет с потоком(который читает слово из
>   памяти),когда из него переключатся на другой.Он все равно продолжит
>   считывание?

Нет, остановленный поток не будет ничего считывать или записывать. Остановленный поток будет стоять и ждать, пока его снова запустят.

Когда планировщик переключает потоки, то планировщик не знает, что делает поток. На самом деле поток постоянно читает что-то из памяти и пишет в память и его всегда прерывают либо на чтении либо на записи. :-) Когда поток прерывается, то все его состояния запоминаются и запускается другой поток. А остановленный поток ждет, когда его снова запустят.

UPD1:

> Поток то не будет, а вот процессор продолжит читать. Dma всеж

Естественно что если один поток остановлен, то это не значит, что остановлен процессор. Процессор переключается на другой поток и продолжает работу. И DMA тут совершенно не при чем. Если переключение потоков происходит во время работы контроллера DMA, то контроллер DMA продолжает свою работу. А прерывание в конце работы контроллера DMA должно указывать, какому потоку/процессу принадлежат данные.

Comment: Поток то не будет, а вот процессор продолжит читать. Dma всеж